# Do I really need an Anti-Virus software if I'm careful about where I browse?

Tags: virus, malware

A friend told to me the following:

> I don't use Anti-Virus software at all, I am just careful about where I go and what I click on.

I've also heard this from other people as I've repaired their PC's and cleaned up the malware/viruses they've received from browsing to the "wrong" sites.  Finally I found [this blog post](http://exodusdev.com/blog/mike/living-dangerously-no-anti-virus-or-firewall) that states:

> To be blunt: I refused to install any kind of antivirus or personal firewall software on most of my computers (but see Update 1/1/2012, below.) This included a Windows XP Home system that was used by my children as a web surfing / email / game system. I suffered zero infections during this time.

My question is, are there any documented studies that either prove or disprove these claims of being able to browse the internet carefully and having the same amount of risk of infection as that of browsing the internet **with** anti-virus software?

<sup>*Note: I thought I remembered seeing a Screen Savers episode one time where they had a PC connected to the internet without any anti-malware or anti-virus and by the end of the show the computer was rendered useless but I couldn't seem to find it.*</sup>

Comment: @Beofett I believe that they are more about corporate security, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: There could be viruses delivered via exploits in banner ads that load on a webpage. Or you could plug in a flash drive with a virus (even if autorun is disabled, see Stuxnet). I personally run with my A/V autoscan turned off and keep my machine patched, but I've seen a few occasions where an A/V scanner detected and cleaned an infection just from browsing to a page with a malicious ad.

Comment: @Bigbio2002 : No Antivirus program caught Stuxnet.

Comment: I don't know if there are any studies, but `I suffered zero infections during this time.` could just mean, has was unable to detect the infections. Actual malware tries to avoid to be detected, can be caught just be `drive by` and many reputated sites have been used already for attacks. [Malicious Ads Detected on Double Click Network of Google](http://www.spamfighter.com/News-16733-Malicious-Ads-Detected-on-Double-Click-Network-of-Google.htm) [drive by infections](https://www.ebankingabersicher.ch/en/component/content/article/75)

Comment: [a swiss articel about the concepts unfortunately in German](http://www.switch.ch/export/sites/default/all/cert/downloads/measures/_files_analysis/Drive-by-Infection.pdf)

Comment: security.SE is a better fit for this (they have better people to answer), also sites can become malware carriers overnight (even while you browse)

Comment: @ratchetfreak I'm going to give it a few days here, and then if nothing will flag for migration.

Comment: Some conjecture: with identical usage patterns, an antivirus should provide a safety net, and thus be safer than not having one.  It's difficult to compare different usage patterns, e.g. if you can live with a [text-based browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser), you've probably made your attack surface so small (and your software profile so atypical) that you are unlikely to ever run across a virus.  Anecdotally, I've also run antivirus-free Windows installs for several years without (detected) infections, so I'm sure it's *possible*.

Comment: @danielb how could you detect a virus if you had nothing to detect it?

Comment: Both statements you cite are absolutely misguidedf. Any legitimate site that has user-generated content (including ebay, Amazon, etc.) can have XSS vulnerabilities that enable attackes to use those sites to infect visitors via drive-by downloads. This happens very, very frequently.

Comment: @KronoS Mainly by monitoring my outgoing connections, and (very) occasionally performing an offline scan of my drives.  I guess it would be more accurate to say that I never used realtime protection, not that I never used any anti-malware software at all.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Maybe I misunderstand, but: How are drive-by downloads (or any other malicious web content) an argument for using an antivirus? These should be handled by sandboxing in the browser. Keeping the browser uptodate should be the most effective solution. On the other side, if my browser would really be vunerable to a drive-by-web-attack I highly doubt that the AV would be capable to fingerprint all malicious js that would be thrown at me.  How can an antivirus detect XSS attacks, these should be handled by a) the browser  b) the admin of the website so what has AV to do with it?

Comment: @logicalx2: There are new vulnerabilities in browser sandboxes being discovered almost every single day. An AV that monitors your downloads gives you a second line of defense, and they don't necessarily have to stop the JS that uses the exploit, they get a second chance when that exploit downloads a trojan, rootkit, whatever. And their analysis goes far beyond simple fingerprinting these days.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As mentioned in some of the comments, there are no sites which can be guaranteed safe. Even reputable sites have suffered through banner ads, coding mistakes, deliberate attacks etc. so the first problem is that you cannot trust any website. You can work out a level of likelihood of safety by looking at the code from a sandbox and following links, but many attackers write code that hides from debugging tools or from testing environments, and code often changes attack vector with time.

So, to the next part - do you need an antivirus? Absolutely - a huge number of machines connected to the Internet are infected and running as part of botnets. If you don't protect your machine it may end up attacking mine. If you cannot detect malware on your machine I would blame your detection techniques, not think that your machine was clean.

From SANS, [Expected infection time for an unprotected machine on the Internet is sub-5 minutes!](https://isc.sans.edu/survivaltime.html) *(survivaltime is calculated as the average time between reports for an average target IP address ... aka someone pinging your computer would count as an "infection")*

Sure, AV is only one layer of security (or potentially 2 if you use AV at gateway and desktop) but all layers have value. Any that you miss increases the likelihood of successful compromise.

Comment: "If you don't protect your machine it may end up attacking mine." I like that statement. Interesting perspective. It makes me think of the shared social responsibility of vaccination.

Comment: @RyanRies: and it completely dismisses the fact that *none* of the AVs can protect you from all threats, especially low-profile ones.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: since this appears to be a quasi-religious argument and I don't have a diamond or several k rep next to my name, I think I'll just leave it at this quote of myself from my answer (which attracted already one downvote): "Strictly speaking we can *never* tell whether a system is clean, whereas we can state that ***we** didn't find anything*."

Comment: What does "unprotected" mean in the statement "Expected infection time for an unprotected machine on the Internet is sub-5 minutes!"

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: running Windows without real-time AV protection for the past 10 years, visiting US sites. Only ~3 infections, and those were from running IE or Chrome in an anonymous tab without Ad Block. I run offline scans periodically and the most they find are cookies.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58921/discussion-on-answer-by-rory-alsop-do-i-really-need-an-anti-virus-software-if-i).

Comment: I generaly considere what you say as an evidence (due to the diamond...) but do you have any reference for *Expected infection time for an unprotected machine on the Internet is sub-5 minutes!*? Because a client machine only protected by a box NAT should expect little attacks except those driven by why lies between the keyboard and the chair... I of course run an antivirus because I know the more defense lines the better, but the only alerts it has sent me since I have started using it (now several years) are when I have tried *weird* sites from a dedicated snapshoted VM, and some mails...

Comment: @RoryAlsop "Expected infection time for an unprotected machine on the Internet is sub-5 minutes" could you please provide your source

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction Yeah, that statement is really misleading. Especially since an Antivirus program would do pretty much nothing to protect you against someone gaining access to your computer through a RCE exploit that can own your machine using nothing but network access to it. The proper tool to defend against that sort of attack is a firewall, and those are built-in to almost every major OS and router on the planet.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem very convincing to me. The first paragraph just essentially says "sites can be compromised" without explaining how that would result in your computer being infected. (In general, web browsers don't let random sites you visit get full user-level permissions on your computer.) And the second paragraph makes vague statements about the existence of botnets and the need to "protect your machine" without demonstrating that AV systems actually help with either of those problems. Your comments about "layers of security" would be a much better way to approach this question IMO.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm not saying the SANS data is incorrect or invalid, I'm saying it does very little to support your point, since a) it is not a measurement of actual infections, only connection attempts and b) you present no evidence that an AV system would do anything to stop infections via this vector (especially considering a simple firewall sounds like it would be much better suited for dealing with this particular threat model). In this context I'd even say the way its presented is misleading, since it would be easy to misinterpret "unprotected" to mean "does not have an AV system installed".

Answer (score 22):

There are many many angles to this question and I won't be able to cover all.

Up front a partial disclosure, I am working in the AV industry, but I won't give any more details. Another disclosure, I haven't been using any "realtime" AV mechanisms on my private machines in the past ten or so years. However, I have run offline scans on my machines from time to time.

### Several angles to look at the problem

Drive-by-infections and trojans are but two of the potential attack vectors, so careful browsing will *not* completely relieve you of using common sense or doing your homework in other areas (keeping your software patched and such). There are many more, including targeted (usually known as "spear-fishing", "social engineering") attacks.

#### Underestimated potential for attacks

For example it has been shown by researchers that placing a USB key that looks like a flash drive but behaves like storage + mouse + keyboard can be used to get into otherwise highly secured areas. No one thinks of an attack first when finding a USB flash drive, right? But it could be.

Anyway, there are many more attack vectors on a wider scale. Most common examples include:

- vulnerabilities in software you use

  - Adobe Flash and Adobe Reader: PDFs (embedding JavaScript or Flash ... or nested combinations) - when on Windows, I suggest to use [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/), as it simply doesn't support scripts or Flash inside PDFs.
  - The various browser engines
  - Simple rendering of strings can exploit vulnerabilities (found in the past [in font rendering](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.de/2015/07/one-font-vulnerability-to-rule-them-all.html))
  - Java when used as a browser plugin (although not really necessary any more these days unless you visit a lot of websites from the 1990s ;))
  - use of a number of complex and/or proprietary file formats (pictures, documents ...) where the software decoding the file format is more error-prone.
  - the operating system components themselves: think of the Blaster worm and WannaCry worm/ransomware.
- turning your own brain off at the wrong moment

  - getting an email from a loved one with an attachment? Uh oh, email senders can be faked like postcards. You can use cryptographically signed mails to guard against this. Better yet, you can use PGP/[GPG](https://www.gpg4win.de/) to guard against anyone else but you and your loved one *reading* the contents by also encrypting it; the electronic counterpart of an envelope, just not as easy to "open".
  - actually going to some "erotic" site and just to see that one image or video executing that "downloader" or "viewer"
- Firmware can be "trojanized" so that your OS doesn't get the slightest chance to detect any wrongdoing on part of the computer.

  - Bluepill by Joanna Rutkowska was a similar approach in that it uses virtualization instructions to move the running system into the guest position while the rootkit itself retains the position as hypervisor.

To just name a few. Microsoft's own [EMET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Mitigation_Experience_Toolkit) has proven useful many times over in pre-empting certain kinds of exploits. But it won't be a silver bullet. If you are on a Windows edition that allows for it, you can also set **Software Restriction Policies** and **Application Control Policies**. Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't seem to give those a lot of love anymore and since the enforcement of SHA-2 hashed signatures, the ACPs don't work reliably anymore on the basis of the signatures. However, you can still use them with file hash rules.

Btw: the inverse is also true. One could also engineer a mouse or a keyboard that includes storage and triggers the execution of something off that storage. [Here's a project](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1186217328/the-glitch) that makes this accessible to a wider audience.

#### Wrong conclusions

But let's look at the quote you gave.

> To be blunt: I refused to install any kind of antivirus or personal
>   firewall software on most of my computers (but see Update 1/1/2012,
>   below.) This included a Windows XP Home system that was used by my
>   children as a web surfing / email / game system. I suffered zero
>   infections during this time.

That clearly shows that the quoted person is not very knowledgeable about the subject. **No one, including AV vendors can tell you with 100% certainty that you *aren't infected*.** It's a silly claim. Just because there is no sign of infection doesn't mean there is no infection. A malware may lay dormant for a long time, for example, just to kick in at some particular point (think about the [Michelangelo virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelangelo_(computer_virus))) There are very few methods, usually involving live CDs/DVDs (example [Qubes](http://qubes-os.org/)) which will protect against most attack vectors, but one can usually come up with a scenario where they fail. The most practical are sandboxes that separate programs from each other and this is the approach that Qubes uses.

What I'm saying is that the person uses the wrong justifications and makes the wrong conclusions - *not that there is anything wrong with not using AV programs*.

#### AVs won't protect you necessarily, especially pure AVs

> My question is, are there any documented studies that either prove or
>   disprove these claims of being able to browse the internet carefully
>   and having the same amount of risk of infection as that of browsing
>   the internet with anti-virus software?

Again, browsing isn't the only attack vector through which malware can enter your system (the autorun mechanism in Windows together with a vulnerability in the icon handler for link files allowed Stuxnet to spread). It was as easy as plugging a flash drive into the computer. The next thing is that a pure AV solution will not filter the websites you access and will only trigger whenever something hits the disk (can also be the browser cache, though). So this makes it clear that a pure AV solution doesn't provide a very good protection against browsing-related infections in the first place.

However, we can assume that most malware needs to persist on the users' machines to be useful to its author - unlike in the past when malware authors proved their knowledge through the creation of viruses and such, these days malware writing is very much a quasi-commercial endeavor - such as skimming banking data or using the GPU for Bitcoin mining or ransoming and what not.

So when it hits the disk, the AV can catch it. Provided that the AV knows about it. And make no mistake, most AV vendors have long departed from the overcome signature-based detection or only use them as a supplementary detection method. That's contrary to popular belief that I have seen voiced time and time again. I am only aware of a single vendor that is basically sticking with the old ways of signature-based detection. The majority of vendors uses a detection that will catch usually hundreds or thousands of related malware samples at once. Still, the AV company has to have come across the malware in order to detect it. And the more samples it finds for a family, the better it can fine-tune its heuristics to avoid false positives.

It's a race and in the end also an arms race. Malware writers are using [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) and other similar sites (as well as darknet versions of those services) in order to find out whether their creations get detected. Since there is money to be made, be it directly or by renting out your infected machine as a bot, there is enough incentive to keep a low profile.

#### Dispelling a myth ...

Just for those *believers in AVs* the results you see in many, if not most, of the certifications are severely skewed. That has to do with two things:

1. some of them want payment and that of course creates and obstacle for disgruntling the (paying) AV vendors
2. most of the tests allow for loopholes that are mercilessly abused in favor of test results to show off in the respective marketing reports of the vendors

In my opinion one of the better tests is the RAP (Reactive and Proactive) test which measures how good AVs are doing with "outdated" virus signatures. But there are certainly more things that would have to be improved in order to make these tests more objective.

Since I originally wrote this answer there's an effort underway, called [AMTSO](http://www.amtso.org/), to make tests more meaningful to anti-malware solutions' customers. At this time I am unsure it'll bring the promised improvements, but the future will tell. At the very least it has become clear that since the vendors outnumber the testers there seems to be a bias inherent in decisions and guidelines. But at least awareness of that issue exists.

### Conclusion: *you can't buy security*

AVs *will* provide an additional layer of security to the layman and even to the expert. Period. But - and that's a big but - this added security can never offset lack of education in security-aware computer use. Conversely I hold that, yes, if you are paranoid and diligent enough you *don't need* an AV as in **a must have**. The technological layer of protection will not offset the protection you gain from due diligence, paranoia and most importantly *awareness*.

**The security provided by an AV can very much be compared to airport security.** There's a lot of security show, but there's also some *actual* added security involved. But don't believe that the AV will protect you - or others for that matter - a 100% from getting infected. Which can also be read as a shameless plug for any backup solution (be sure to keep backups offline, so they don't get wiped by ransomware, for example).

In my opinion the best protection by far is awareness and diligence. But unfortunately there is nothing like a driver's license required for computer or internet use. So failing that the next best protection would be sandboxes, whitelisting approaches and also AVs and other anti-malware solutions *in addition to regular offline-stored backups*. They'll never be able to give you a 100% protection (well, whitelisting *might*), but they can protect you from a wide range of prolific threats. So when in doubt, *sure* go for that AV (or in general anti-malware) solution. But that's where it gets difficult. They differ in quality and even the tests - as I pointed out above - are often severely skewed. Adding another AV engine into the mix may help but there's no guarantee. If inside of a single product, the integration of several engines will likely be good and not add too much overhead. However, if you install several AV products in parallel you are asking for trouble. In fact modern Windows versions only allow you to see the stats of a single security solution per category in the Windows Action/Security Center.

As for whitelisting, recent Windows versions are pretty cool about that. You can effectively implement this yourself (run `gpedit.msc`) in the *Software Restriction Policies* and the *Application Control Policies* (or your admin can do that if you're running in some managed environment). I *think* it was introduced at least since Windows 7, but it's possible that these facilities even existed on Windows Vista. Unfortunately this feature may depend on the edition of your Windows version, which is a shame. There's also a catch in that if you base the rules on code-signatures, this may fail with executables that are only SHA-2 signed.

**Also:**

> keep in mind: Strictly speaking we can *never* tell whether a
>   system is clean, whereas we can state that ***we*** didn't find
>   anything. Every claim to the contrary is either Marketingese or is
>   going to obsolete the AV industry as a whole quickly.
>
> (source: my answer over on SuperUser [here](https://superuser.com/a/558004/68747))

A yet better security net are backups and frequent rollbacks to a known-clean state - but that's just in my opinion.

#### Commercialized malware doesn't need privileged access, not even on Linux, FreeBSD or macOS

Over on SuperUser I wrote [this](https://superuser.com/a/558004/68747):

> One more thing. Many Linux (also MacOSX) users fall prey to the
>   assumption that malware that doesn't have privileged access can't hurt
>   you (which is also often cited as a reason why there "isn't" malware
>   for unixoid systems, which also isn't entirely true). This couldn't be
>   further from the truth. Although this prevents it from establishing a
>   system-wide stronghold, it won't keep malware from skimming data from
>   your personal files etc. A rogue browser extension installed in your own profile will still be *as dangerous to your account* as the one that can do it to all accounts. If you do your internet banking with the
>   rogue extension installed, it makes no difference whether you are
>   `root` or `joe`.

Comment: While I agree with most of this, I would actually suggest that you do need AV/anti malware - even if you are aware and experienced in security.

Comment: Firewall does not equal security. All a firewall typically does is limit the routes in, but in browsing to a website the firewall is supposed to allow replies. Anattacker doesn't even need to bypass your firewall here.

Comment: The figures don't agree with you. And I think you might be misunderstanding this scenario. Folks like Palo Alto are starting to make inroads, but it is early days for them.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Agree with your assessment completely. Drive by downloads are not magic. It only happens because of a) an 0-day exploit for a fully updated browser b) human stupidity. In the first case, if it is a targed 0-day, then AV is a fail there in the first place because it hasn't seen the sample before. And in the second case, if the operator is stupid, trust me AV can't protect the machine.

Comment: "malware doesn't need privileged access" reminds me of this: https://xkcd.com/1200/

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to make an analogy: Do I need a condom when I'm really careful when having sex? Yes you do because even when you are safe you don't know the other party involved is even if he or she says they are.So do you need to use a condom/anti virus? Of  course you do, better be safe than sorry as getting rid of a virus is very hard.

Do note that even when using an anti virus things can go wrong even when you are being safe! If you suspect things have gone wrong it is best to restore from backup or perform a clean install.

Comment: Unfortunately it happens so that you live a hundred years BCE, what do you do? STDs did exist back then. Would common sense and/or paranoia help or not?

Comment: STDs existed and people got infected and died from them. So the solution would be not to have sex. In this case this would mean not to install software or go on the internet.

Comment: oh I think we just have a little problem as to why humanity still exists and the majority of children isn't born with STDs. All I am saying is that your comparison doesn't compute ;) ... at least for me. If it works for others, fine :)

Comment: Not all STDs are deadly and not every virus kills your computer, it's just annoying.

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://www.ashasexualhealth.org/std-sti/std-statistics.html

Comment: Note as well when you say a child is born we can compare that to a brand new computer, but when that childs start screwing around the chances of catching are quite high. 80% of all people get infected with HPV at one point in their life.

Comment: My point is you don't *need* your condom, but it makes sense and provides an additional security net that can, however, fail. When you say you *need* something that's an absolute statement. And I hold that there is no such need. That's the difference between a *requirement* and a *recommendation* for me. And the OP clearly asked for a particular scenario, not for the run-of-the-mill computer use. Again, you can't buy security and if there would be a screencast/tutorial included in an AV subscription it'd be much more effective than the technology alone.

Comment: I completely agree on that

Comment: Computers != organisms